# Change priority inside a priorityQueue

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

I try to write a program using a priorityQueue ADT ( the documentation is found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html ). The priorityQueue orders instances of a nested class *Node* which has two variables: an integer representing the weight (or the priority) and a String representing the information to be stored inside the queue.

The problem I face is to change an element's priority (i.e. its weight) without pulling the element out of the queue ( using the function *remove()* ) and then pushing a new one with the new priority ( using the function *add()* ). I would like to be able to change the integer representing the weight inside an instance of a class *Node* inside the queue and then the priorityQueue will reorder itself to find if there is a new Node to place at the head of the queue.

And a last thing: I don't *have to* use the priorityQueue ADT. If there is any other ADT that resolves this issue in a more elegant manner, be free to mention it!

I am pretty sure I'm not the first person to encounter this difficulty so I'm sorry if there is already an answer to this question anywhere on this website but I haven't found it.

Comment: In short, you want/need to create a priority queue using Nodes for the implementation rather than an array? Good luck with that :)

Comment: As I said in my question, if there is any other ADT than the priorityQueue ADT that can achieve this goal, it's ok for me :)